# "assignment of read-only member" error when assigning to non const member of a struct

Tags: c, embedded, fsm

I am trying to create a FSM in C. I am using a variation of the STATE pattern for C that is explained [here](http://www.adamtornhill.com/Patterns%20in%20C%202,%20STATE.pdf). The problem is that I am in the embedded world and they make me comply with some safety-critical rules. One of these rules says that I can't use non-const pointers to functions, so I have created my fsm like this:

```
typedef struct tFsm* tFsmPtr;

/* PLEASE NOTE: This is a non const struct with its member
 * being a const pointer to a function.  */
typedef struct
{
    void (*const raise)(tFsmPtr);
} tEvent;

struct tFsm
{
    /* Because the tEvent type is non const,
     * I can modify these fields */
    tEvent start;
    tEvent started;
    tEvent stop;
    tEvent stopped;
};

static void DefaultInvalidEventCallback(tFsmPtr fsm)
{
    /* Raise an error */
}

static struct tFsm m_fsm = {
    .start   = { .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback },
    .started = { .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback },
    .stop    = { .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback },
    .stopped = { .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback }
};
```

No errors so far. The problem is that when I try to modify any field of the `struct tFsm`, it complains. For example this code:

```
void ResetFsm( tFsmPtr fsm )
{
    fsm->start       = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
    fsm->started     = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
    fsm->stop        = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
    fsm->stopped     = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
}
```

The compiler complains saying that:

```
prog.c: In function 'ResetFsm':
prog.c:32:22: error: assignment of read-only member 'start'
     fsm->start       = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
                      ^
prog.c:33:22: error: assignment of read-only member 'started'
     fsm->started     = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
                      ^
prog.c:34:22: error: assignment of read-only member 'stop'
     fsm->stop        = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
                      ^
prog.c:35:22: error: assignment of read-only member 'stopped'
     fsm->stopped     = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
                      ^
```

My questions are:
Could you please tell me why the compiler complains here?
Is there a way of using const pointers to functions here?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Because of `const` in `tEvent`?....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member `raise` of struct `tEvent`, is defined with const:

```
void (*const raise)(tFsmPtr);
```

This means that only initialization of the entire struct is possible:

```
tEvent s = { DefaultInvalidEventCallback };
```

but assignment of the entire struct is not:

```
tEvent a;
a = s;
```

This of course holds true for any struct which has the struct `tEvent` as its member, for example: `struct tFsm`, as shown in your example

Answer (score 1):

For any struct where you have a `const` member, you can only set the member when you initialize the struct. You cannot change it in run-time, for the very same reasons as you cant do this:

```
const int x=1; 
x=2;
```

You have created an [immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Since you aren't allowed to use non-constant function pointers, the function `ResetFsm` doesn't make any sense and needs to be removed. There is no way you can write it so that it makes sense.

What you could do instead is something like:

```
struct tFsm CreateDefaultFsm (void)
{
  return (struct tFsm)
  {
    .start    = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback },
    .started  = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback },
    .stop     = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback },
    .stopped  = (tEvent){ .raise = &DefaultInvalidEventCallback },
  };
}
```

You can also create a similar copy function etc. All functions that work on the struct has to create a new copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way, just cast away the const when setting, e.g.

```
*(int *)&struct->const_int = 10;
```

and:

```
const mystruct_type myconst_struct;
((*mystruct_type)&myconst_struct)->val = 20;
```

The compiler won't generate a warning when the address of a const variable is cast to a non-const address.